# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script

Tags: compiling, intel, 20.04, qt, qmake

So I've recently done a (fresh) installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm trying to install [IBOview](http://iboview.org/_bgBqyRo.html), which I had working on 18.04 LTS. As it describes in the README, and as I successfully did before, I tried to compile it with `qmake-qt4 -o Makefile main.pro && make -j 4` but it prints the following error:

`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script`

The program requires the intel MKL libraries, which I have installed via Intel's install.sh script. Furthermore, I've added the MKL directory to main.pro so it can 'see' them. What kind of error is this? i.e. is it from qmake? I'm at a bit of a loss to be honest. The intel MKL installer told me that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not officially supported so if that's the problem I guess I will just downgrade to 19.10 LTS which is...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu 20.04 LTS shipping Qt5, so you have to use it.

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget http://iboview.org/bin/ibo-view.20150427.tar.bz2
tar -xf ibo-view.20150427.tar.bz2
cd ibo-view.20150427/

sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qt5-default qtscript5-dev libqt5svg5-dev
```

Also you need to install Boost libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

along with [Intel MKL](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/intel-mkl)

```
sudo apt-get install libmkl-interface-dev libmkl-computational-dev libmkl-threading-dev
```

And then compile the software:

```
qmake main.pro
make -j4
```

And run it:

```
./iboview
```